# Reading a key and getting the section from .ini file in c++/MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have an .ini file with sections like:

```
[Hai1]
Value1 = 1
Value2 = 2

[Hai2]
Value1 = 3
Value2 = 4
```

Now, I need to search for a particular key like "value1 = 3" and have to get the corresponding section to which it belongs, in this case "Hai2".To use GetPrivateProfileString we need the section first. But in my case I need to get a particular section based on the Key value.Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no Win32 function that does this for you, but parsing an ini file by yourself shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Michal Walz ...Yes,we do not have any API for that. I am using GetPrivateProfileSectionNames funtion to get all section names and I have my method to get the required section based on Key value .... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse all the sections. Get the section names via GetPrivateProfileSectionNames.

```
char lpszReturnBuffer[4096];
DWORD nSize;     
nSize = sizeof(lpszReturnBuffer);

DWORD dwRet = GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(lpszReturnBuffer, nSize, lpszFileName);

while (strlen(lpszReturnBuffer)>0) 
{
    TRACE(lpszReturnBuffer);
    SearchForMyKeyValueInSection(lpszReturnBuffer);
    lpszReturnBuffer+= strlen(lpszReturnBuffer)+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an INI file parser. If you can use the Boost library, see [Boost::PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/property_tree.html)